# Pull through product data in Shopify

Tags: json, shopify, liquid

I am making my own product slider for my website. 
I have my own dynamic section, where in 'customise theme' you can select 5 products.

I can pull through the product handle with {{ section.settings.product-1 }} , but how can  I get the product id, product name, product price, product image url etc..?

Things, like {{ product.title }} don't work, because it doesn't know where to pull the information from.

My current code is:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="section-header text-center">
    <h2 class="h1 section-header__title"> {{ section.settings.text-box }} 
    </h2>
  </div>

  <div class="rte">

    <div class="gallery js-flickity" data-flickity-options='{ "freeScroll": true, "wrapAround": true }'>
       <div class="gallery-cell"> </div>
       <div class="gallery-cell"> Text </div>
       <div class="gallery-cell"> Text </div>
       <div class="gallery-cell"> Text </div> 
   </div>
 </div>
</div>

{% schema %}
{
"name": "Featured Slider",
"settings": [

{
    "id" : "text-box",
    "type" : "text",
    "label" : "Title of Section",
    "default" : "Featured Products"
},

{
    "type" : "product",
    "id" : "product-1",
    "label" : "Featured Product"
},

{
    "type" : "product",
    "id" : "product-2",
    "label" : "Featured Product"
},

{
    "type" : "product",
    "id" : "product-3",
    "label" : "Featured Product"
},

{
    "type" : "product",
    "id" : "product-4",
    "label" : "Featured Product"
},

{
    "type" : "product",
    "id" : "product-5",
    "label" : "Featured Product"
}],

"presets": [
    {
    "name" : "Featured Product Slider",
    "category" : "Allsops Sections"
    }
        ]
 }
{% endschema %}
```

So the idea is in each gallery-cell div will be a different product.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you are using a section which is great but you are not using it in a useful way.

Sections provides a very nice addition to your code logic - Blocks ( a.k.a dynamic content )

```
{% schema %}
{
    "name": "Featured Slider",
    "settings": [
        {
            "id" : "text-box",
            "type" : "text",
            "label" : "Title of Section",
            "default" : "Featured Products"
        }
    ],
    "blocks": [
        {
            "type": "slide",
            "name": "Slide",
            "settings": [
            {
                "id": "product",
                "type": "product",
                "label": "Featured Products"
            }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "presets": [
        {
            "name" : "Featured Product Slider",
            "category" : "Allsops Sections"
        }
    ]
}
{% endschema %}

{% for block in section.blocks %}
    {% assign product = all_products[block.settings.product] %}
    <div class="slider">
        <a href="{{ product.url }}">
            <img src="{{ product.featured_image | img_url: 'master' }}">
            {{ product.title }}
        </a>
    </div>
    ...
{% endfor %}
```

This way you can add as many slides as you like and reorder them the way you like.

As for your question, you get the product using the `all_products` object to get a specific object. In the schema I provided you can see that I use it here `{% assign product = all_products[block.settings.product] %}`

**Please note that `all_products` allows for only 20 request, any more than that and it will throw a liquid error.**

Comment: Thank you very much! - It all makes sense too, thanks for the explanation.